# SQL Server - Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have read some posts here about it but I do not understand at all.

In my case I have a table, let's say 'Parent' with two columns **ID**, **DELETED**.

ID is int and DELETED is a bit column.

I have another table, let's say 'Child' with columns ID, ID_PARENT, NAME, DELETED as Parent Table.

ID and ID_PARENT are int
NAME is nvarchar
DELETED is a bit

I have created a trigger FOR UPDATE on table Parent which updates Child table:

```
UPDATE 
       [dbo].[Child]
   SET 
       [DELETED] = I.[DELETED]         
  FROM 
       INSERTED I INNER JOIN [dbo].[Child] AS c
       ON I.ID = c.ID_PARENT
 WHERE 
       c.[NAME] IS NOT NULL;
```

Keep in mind that one parent may have many childs, and one child only one parent.

So when I do below query:

```
  UPDATE [dbo].[Parent]
     SET DELETED = 1
   WHERE ID IN (100, 200);
```

Of course, this will affect to many rows. I get below error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Check your triggers - I bet you have one that runs on `Update` which assumes only one row will be updated at once (e.g. is poorly designed)

Comment: @Bridge You are right. I have checked other triggers and there is one on table Child that is causing the error. Thanks!

Comment: No problem - please post an answer to that effect and accept it, so others know your question is resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you have already resolved your question. In comment section you have mentioned that you have triggered created on child. But for other community users here is complete scenario creation with solution.

```
CREATE TABLE TempParent
(
    ID INT,
    DELETED BIT
)
GO
CREATE TABLE TempChild
(
    ID INT, 
    ID_PARENT int,
    NAME varchar(100), 
    DELETED BIT
 )

INSERT INTO TempParent
SELECT 
    100,0 UNION ALL
SELECT 
    200,0 UNION ALL  
SELECT 
    300,0 UNION ALL
SELECT 
    400,0 
GO
INSERT INTO  TempChild
 SELECT 
    100,100,'Rahul',0 UNION ALL
SELECT 
    200,200,'Rajesh',0 UNION ALL  
SELECT 
    300,300,'Anil',0 UNION ALL
SELECT 
    400,400,NULL,0 

GO       
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_TempParent
ON dbo.TempParent
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE 
        [dbo].TempChild
    SET 
        [DELETED] = I.[DELETED]         
    FROM 
        INSERTED I INNER JOIN [dbo].TempChild AS c
        ON I.ID = c.ID_PARENT
 WHERE 
       c.[NAME] IS NOT NULL;
END
GO
SELECT * FROM TempParent

SELECT * FROM TempChild

UPDATE [dbo].TempParent
SET DELETED = 1
WHERE ID IN (100, 200);

DROP TABLE TempParent
DROP TABLE TempChild
```

Comment: Yes this is the correct scenario. My problem was that there was another trigger that was being raised and this trigger was assuming only one row being updated at once.